# Search using parentheses and single quote

Tags: deezer

Im using advanced search with track and title, but there seems to be a problem either with the single quote or the parentheses in the query.

With the complete title I'm not getting the correct track:

```
https://api.deezer.com/search?q=track:"(I Don't Feel Like) Giving In" artist:"Sea Pinks"&limit=1&output=json
```

Only if I remove the parentheses part:

```
https://api.deezer.com/search?q=track:"Giving In" artist:"Sea Pinks"&limit=1&output=json
```